# How can I free up space from my (big enough) /boot?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get

I'm trying to install Plex Media Server to my Ubuntu server (14.04.2 LTS) following this [guide](https://thelinuxexperiment.com/running-a-containerized-media-server-with-ubuntu-14-04-docker-and-plex/) but as soon as I get to installing Docker I'm getting the following issue when I run the command `sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-53-generic is already the newest version.
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-53-generic set to manually installed.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-68-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-68-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-68-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Then when I try to run the command `apt-get -f install` I'm getting the following error:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.13.0-48 linux-headers-3.13.0-48-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-54 linux-headers-3.13.0-54-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-48-generic linux-image-3.13.0-54-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-48-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-54-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.13.0-68-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc-3.13.0 linux-source-3.13.0 linux-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.13.0-68-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 205 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/15.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 42.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 316302 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.13.0-68-generic_3.13.0-68.111_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.13.0-68-generic (3.13.0-68.111) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-68-generic_3.13.0-68.111_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/System.map-3.13.0-68-generic' to '/boot/System.map-3.13.0-68-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-68-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-68-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-68-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-68-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-68-generic_3.13.0-68.111_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Now, by reading the error message I know the `/boot/` drive is full and looking at `$ df -h` it does seem like it's full. But what is the best way to empty the drive or could I move the `/boot/` to a bigger partition without affecting all the files on the main drive?

** **Update** **

This is how the output of my `df -h` looks like:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  1.8T  1.5T  256G  86% /
none                         4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                         968M  8.0K  968M   1% /dev
tmpfs                        196M  1.2M  195M   1% /run
none                         5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                         980M  4.0K  980M   1% /run/shm
none                         100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1                    236M  230M     0 100% /boot
```

And here the output of my `dpkg -l 'linux-image*' | grep ^ii`:

```
$ dpkg -l 'linux-image*' | grep ^ii
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic            3.13.0-43.72                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-46-generic            3.13.0-46.79                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-48-generic            3.13.0-48.80                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-49-generic            3.13.0-49.83                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-51-generic            3.13.0-51.84                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-52-generic            3.13.0-52.86                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-53-generic            3.13.0-53.89                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic      3.13.0-43.72                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-46-generic      3.13.0-46.79                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-48-generic      3.13.0-48.80                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-49-generic      3.13.0-49.83                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-51-generic      3.13.0-51.84                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-52-generic      3.13.0-52.86                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-53-generic      3.13.0-53.89                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

Comment: Please post the output of `df -h` and `dpkg -l 'linux-image*' | grep ^ii`. The first command will give you a table showing available and used space for every mounted file systems, whereas the second a list of all installed kernels.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the original post with the output of the commands.

Answer (score 2):

Your /boot directory is full! Find and remove the older kernels that you don't use anymore and remove them(apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic). Why do you have so many? Just keep a couple to fall back on and a new one. This will make your boot list shorter as well.

Comment: Probably because `apt` installs a new package for every kernel update, but does not automatically remove the unneeded ones.

Comment: @simon-tan: When I try to run that command I get the following error: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-68-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-68-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-68-generic but it is not going to be installed`

Comment: Try: apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic. Do the same for the rest. Remember to keep at least one(the one that works on your machine) or your computer won't boot up.

Comment: @simontan I tried that command too, but then I get this: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-68-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-68-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-68-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`

Answer (score 1):

Following this guide on askubuntu.com solved my problem:

→ [Freeing Up Space on the /boot File System](https://askubuntu.com/a/423741)
(obviously replacing the relevant values to my own where needed)

After following the guide above I ran the command `apt-get autoremove` and that cleared up a whole bunch of space on my /boot partition.

Now I'm able to run the command `apt-get -f install` again.